# how to cofigure slf4j in spring-mvc for logging?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, slf4j

I want to use **SLF4j** in Spring mvc-hibernate project. i have made
 logback.xml for logging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mkyong.web" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

but i do not know to cofigure **logback.xml** in spring-mvc.

In which folder in project should i keep my logback.xml?

how do i configure logback.xml in **DefaultServlet-servlet.xml**

Comment: put it into src/main/resources

Comment: check this steps: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do anything in Spring configuration. Just add the slf4j and logback dependencies (e.g. in pom.xml if you're using maven), keep logback.xml in the classpath (e.g. src/main/resources) and use the SLF4J API in your spring-mvc Controllers.

You can also see more details here:

https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+setup+SLF4J+and+LOGBack+in+a+web+app+-+fast

Comment: thanx for the reply but i am getting error while creating main/resources in src  please check the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907204/how-to-created-src-main-resources-in-eclipse

Comment: The structure src/main/resources is for Maven. If you're not using maven you don't need to create this structure. I strongly recommend you use maven.

Comment: Create a pom.xml in the root folder of your project and then import the project into Eclipse by doing Import->Existing Maven Projects.

Comment: Since you're not using Maven, you shouldn't be creating the src/main/resources folder. Just put logback.xml in the src folder.

Comment: You may want to read this section 2.3.2. Logging

Here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/overview.html if you're having any issues with the code not respecting the Slf4j setup.