# How to create a src/main/resources directory?

Tags: java, eclipse

All my classes were working fine. Then I wanted to create `main/resources` to add `logback.xml` in `main/resources` in my project

I got help from ["How to create main/java inside src"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914927/creating-a-src-main-java-folder-structure-in-eclipse-without-maven)

But after creating the folders I am getting errors in all my classes, and the main folders were converted into packages

[image: directory structure]

How can I add the folder main/resources in my src folder?

Or is there any way to add `logback.xml` in any package in spring MVC?

Comment: If you will create MAVEN project it ll automatically create by eclipse

Comment: due to some reasons i cant use MAVEN

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To add a resource folder in eclipse:

Click on `Build Path`

Click on `Configure Build Path`

(or `Properties` -> `Java Build Path`)

Click on `Source Tab`

[image]

Click on `Add Folder`

[image]

Click on `Create new Folder`

Comment: Tried this and it would create another new source folder instead of normal folder which it would only allows `package` being created within.

Comment: @si_the_nibba why you want to create the source folder if it is already created?

Comment: Oh that was my mistake cuz I would like to create a subdirectory `folder` under `src` instead of another `source folder` which is meaningless.

Comment: this really worked for me, awesome!

Answer (score 9):

The same problem I also encountered while I was learning the spring boot wanted to add logback.xml in resources. 
I am using sts for spring boot. As of my understanding, there are two things your file system folder structure and another sts folder structure.
First I created a folder in your file system at `src/main/` and then add this folder into build path. *

---

For creating a folder follow below image 1,2 and 3

*
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Now at the final step, add newly added resource folder into the build path. by clicking properties or directly build path button. 
`Click on source tab` and then `click on add folder` and `browse the resources folder` and add that's all.  See below image for more description and help.
[image: image 4]

Comment: I tried this one and it work very well for me. Just refresh your maven update and folder is available under the right location in eclise.

Answer (score 5):

Right Click your project -> Build Path -> New Source Folder and Type the name of the the resource folder you want to create like ----->src/main/resources or src/test/resources  ..it will create a new resource folder

Answer (score 3):

Try to add new Source Folder. Right click on your src->New>Source Folder:main/resources

Comment: it ll create folder in java resources folder not in src

Comment: That's because src is not configured as a source folder in your project. Java Resources is. You should use a Source folder for your classes. If you want to convert src folder to a source folder right click on source -> Build Path and select Use as Source Folder

Answer (score 2):

Right Click your project -> Build Path -> New Source Folder

Type the folder path, src/main/resources and click Finish.

Screenshots below.

Step 1: [Figure: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzflz.jpg)

Step 2: [Figure: 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRX0x.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using Maven, you shouldn't be creating the src/main/resources folder. Just put logback.xml in the src folder.

Also move your java files (with their entire package folder structure) back to src as they were before creating the main/resources.

Answer (score 1):

Only maven project automatically generate resource folder inside src, other solution would be put `logbackback.xml` in src folder it ll work.

Answer (score 1):

Locate your `pom.xml`. Navigate to the `build` tag in it. Inside this tag you will have to look for any declaration regarding your source directory. Might be `sourceDirectory` direclty, or it might appear in any of `plugin` as well. Upon finding so, try un-commenting the same and do a **Right Click->Maven->Update Project**. Should solve for most cases. If not you have some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could created the new folder.Then,opening this object's properties and clicking 'Java Build Path'.Reelecting the source folder on build path.Just try,man!

Answer (score 0):

If your project is eclipse project then it will automatically recognize the folders
Open command line, change directory to the folder with the pom.xml
and past this into the CMD:

```
echo This will create all required folders for maven project.
echo creating  Application\Library sources
MD "src\main\java"
echo creating  Application\Library resources
MD "src\main\resources"
echo creating  Resource filter files
MD "src\main\filters"
echo creating  Web application sources
MD "src\main\webapp"
echo creating  Test sources
MD "src\test\java"
echo creating  Test resources
MD "src\test\resources"
echo creating  Test resource filter files
MD "src\test\filters"
echo creating  Integration Tests (primarily for plugins)
MD "src\it"
echo creating  Assembly descriptors
MD "src\assembly"
echo creating  Site
MD "src\site"
```