# REST API queries return a 404?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have created a simple Spring Boot application using REST APIs.  I am using the following controller:

```
package me.hiboy.SpringBootRESTAPI;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BlogController {
    @Autowired
    BlogRepository blogRepository;

    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public List<Blog> index() {
        return blogRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public Blog show(@PathVariable String id) {
        int blogId=Integer.parseInt(id);
        return blogRepository.findOne(blogId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/blog/search")
    public List<Blog> search(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String searchTerm=body.get("text");
        return blogRepository.findByTitleContainingOrContentContaining(searchTerm, searchTerm);
    }

    @PostMapping("/blog")
    public Blog create(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String title=body.get("title");
        String content=body.get("content");

        return blogRepository.save(new Blog(title, content));
    }

    @PutMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public Blog update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        int blogId=Integer.parseInt(id);
        Blog blog=blogRepository.findOne(blogId);
        blog.setTitle(body.get("title"));
        blog.setContent(body.get("content"));

        return blogRepository.save(blog);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public boolean delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        int blogId=Integer.parseInt(id);
        blogRepository.delete(blogId);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the following Entity:

```
package me.hiboy.SpringBootRESTAPI;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Blog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String title;
    private String content;

    public Blog() {}

    public Blog(String title, String content) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setContent(content);
    }

    public Blog(int id, String title, String content) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setContent(content);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title=title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content=content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Blog{" + 
                "id=" + id +  
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' + 
                '}';
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, I am unable to get any response when I visit localhost (I get the 404 response).  Could someone please point out what I must be missing?  It is a simple tutorial which I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@salisuwy/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-a-php-developers-view-part-i-6add2e794646) and the other files that I have built include: `pom.xml`, `application.properties`, `database.sql`, `App.java` (which has my main() function, and the `BlogRepository.java`.

Thanks!

Edit:

App.java is as below:

```
package me.hiboy.SpringBootRESTAPI;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request"})
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

BlogRepository.java is as below:

```
package me.hiboy.SpringBootRESTAPI;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Integer> {
    List<Blog> findByTitleContainingOrContentContaining(String text, String textAgain);
}
```

Edit:

My application.properties is as follows:

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/restapi
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=<my_password_here>
```

Uploading screenshot of the error:

[image]

Edit: While I have completely understood the tutorial, what I fail to understand is the annotation: `@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request"})`.  If this is not included, then I get an error: `Consider defining a bean of type 'me.hiboy.SpringBootRESTAPI.BlogRepository' in your configuration.`  The tutorial that I followed does not include this annotation and I figured this out by following some SO posts.  I wonder what *I did differently* so as to necessitate a requirement for this annotation.  If you could point out, it would be a great help towards my learning and I would highly appreciate it!

Edit:  I have uploaded the entire code on [GitHub](https://github.com/prathemesh/SpringBoot).  It is a fairly simple and straight forward app, but I don't know where I am going wrong! :(

Also, as per my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49884317/9656249), I am not sure about the location of the `resources` folder.  Currently, my directory structure is as follows:

[image: Directory structure]

I am doubtful about this, because all this issue I describe here only started *after I integrated the MySQL database* with this application.  If I simply hard code the values, then the API queries work fine (I don't get a 404).  I am also doubtful because although I mention about port `8086` in the `application.properties` file, it (the WhiteLabel error) still starts on the port `8080`. Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelLiew, well, I get that.  But if people don't see any activity on _this page_, then majority will assume that it is **dead**.  And, I am desperate for help because I am badly stuck since the last 48 hours at a stretch.

Comment: Like for e.g., this page got 6 views since the chat was moved, but none visited the chat page.  Had it been here, then maybe the probability that they would have responded would have increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat/comments section, I am just summing up the points as an answer.

The **resources** folder should be present parallel to the **java** folder under **src/main** and should be marked as resources.

Also, comment the below in App.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request"})
```

Make sure the password is updated under `application.properties` file.

This should work now.

Also, make sure the java version is correct with the compiler compatibility both at runtime and compile time.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Vijay.  This was very helpful for me.  This along with the steps that you took on Team Viewer like changing the java version to 8 and checking the JDBC connections via screen share helped resolve the issue, as you saw.  Thank you! :)